# Java + OpenGL: Texture Z-fighting in batch rendering

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

## **The main issue:**

Good afternoon, everyone. I have such a question, when I use more than two textures in batch rendering, when using 2 textures (that is, my downloaded from disk), it starts glitching with the first texture (white), which in theory should not be because when the second texture is used from the texture slot, it becomes the main one for rendering. And this happens only in the perspective projection, everything is fine with the orthographic projection (most likely because it does not display the distance between objects and the Z-coordinate).

## **Here is a couple images of the issue:**

[image]

[image]

## **Video**

[Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HCxMa9uNrEX1jEMF6gB9qwa_bQIOIDdK/view)

The whole problem is that I have a lot of code written and I think it will not make sense to throw off all of it. I will still show some pieces, but I would like you to express your assumption why this may happen. Maybe it's because I'm binding several texture slots at once. In general, I will be grateful to every advice or answer if it turns out.

## **Draw Sprite using batch rendering (Example)**

```java
    public static void drawRectnagle(GameObject rect) {
        var transform = rect.getComponent(Transform.class);
        var spriteRenderer = rect.getComponent(SpriteRenderer.class);
        
        // Begin new batch if in this batch not has room left.
        if (batch.indexCount >= Batch.maxIndices)
            newBatch();
        
        int        textureIndex = 0;
        Vector2f[] textureCoords = batch.textureCoords;
        Texture texture = null;
        Vector4f color = null;
        if(spriteRenderer != null) {
            texture = spriteRenderer.texture;
            color = spriteRenderer.color;
        } else
            color = new Vector4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
    
        if(texture != null) 
            textureCoords = texture.getTextureCoords();
        else 
            texture = batch.textures[0];
            
        for (int i = 1; i < batch.textureIndex; i++) {
            if (batch.textureIndex >= Batch.maxTextures)
                newBatch();

            // Equal texture by OpenGL ID's.
            if (batch.textures[i].equals(texture)) {
                textureIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if (textureIndex == 0.0f) {
            textureIndex = batch.textureIndex;
            batch.textures[batch.textureIndex] = texture;
            batch.textureIndex++;
        }
        
        ...
        
        // Loading vertex data to batch.
        
        ...
    }
```

## **Rendering batch after setting sprites data (Example)**

```java
    private static void endBatch() {
        if (batch.indexCount == 0)
            return;
        
        int sizeBytes = sizeof(Vertex.class); // NOTE: Size of Vertex class is currect here.
        int size = batch.vertexIndex * sizeBytes;
        batch.vertexBuffer.putData(batch.vertex, size, batch.vertexIndex, sizeBytes / 4);
        
        // Bind each texture from slot.
        for (int i = 0; i < batch.textureIndex; i++) 
            batch.textures[i].bind(i);
            
        RenderEngine.EnableAlphaBlending();
        RenderEngine.EnableDepthTesting();
        glBindVertexArray(batch.vertexArray.get());
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, batch.vertexArray.getIndexBuffer().getCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        RenderEngine.DisableAlphaBlending();
        RenderEngine.DisableDepthTesting();
    }
```

And if someone interest how my putData method works:

```java
    public void putData(Vertex[] vertex, int size, int index, int elementCount) {
        //Convert all Vertex data to single float[] to pass as data in vertex buffer.
        float[] data = ...
        
        if(data != null) { 
            var pData = memAlloc(size).asFloatBuffer().put(data).flip();
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, handle);
            nglBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, memAddress(pData), getOpenGLUsage(usage));
            memFree(pData);
        }
    }
```

## **Fragment Shader**

```c
#version 450 core

layout (location = 0) out vec4 out_Pixel;

in vec3 position;
in vec4 color;
in vec2 textureCoord;
in float textureIndex;

uniform sampler2D u_Textures[32];

void main() {
    vec4 texColour = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
    texColour *= texture(u_Textures[int(textureIndex)], textureCoord);
    
    vec4 finalColor = color * texColour;
    if(finalColor.a < 0.1)
        discard;
    
    out_Pixel = finalColor;
}
```

Comment: Z-fighting only occurs when primitives are rendered on the same plane. Are you rendering a white quad and a textured quad?

Comment: No, i render one single quad with texture.

Comment: I have such a situation first with creating a simple quad without a texture (but in batch rendering, if there is no texture, I have a white texture of 1x1 pixels installed). And then I load 2 textures and add them to the quad.

Comment: If you were only rendering 1 quad, you wouldn't have Z-fighting.

Comment: I know, thats a problem, i dont understand whats happens on GPU at this time.

Comment: Here I made a video there I think it's clearer what exactly is happening. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HCxMa9uNrEX1jEMF6gB9qwa_bQIOIDdK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: is this problem occurring when you disable depth testing or/and alpha blending?

Comment: @Sebphil It seems not, but I just now tried to disable the depth testing and/or alpha blending and re-enable it, but it didn't help all the same glitches.

Comment: @Sebphil It seems to me that he is trying to draw 2 textures from 2 slots on one quad, but then, in fact, the shader should just mix the pixels of 2 textures, but the GPU outputs glitches when I start moving the quad along the Z axis or when rotate it. Moving along the X, Y axis everything is fine.

Comment: Im found the root of the problem is binding texture slots. ```for (int i = 0; i < batch.textureIndex; i++) batch.textures[1].bind(i);``` Im here change ```textures[i].bind(i)``` to ```textures[1].bind(i)``` and glitches totally gone, but next problem is how properly bind multiple textures? Because now situations is that my batch displays one texture on all quads.

Comment: If you only want to bind one texture you can use a [texture-atlas](https://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/130940/practical_texture_atlases.php).

Comment: @Sebphil I know this, but if, for example, you have 2 different atlases and on one quad you use the texture of 1 atlas (some kind of part) and on 2-4 quads you use textures from 2 atlas. And plus, everything you have is batch rendering, where one batch can hold only 32 texture (samplers). Therefore, I will immediately bind all the active slots (which textures are loaded) for rendering.

Comment: If you want to have a property (like offset into the texture atlas/texture index) that is changing between your quads, store it in a vertex buffer. However, this seems like a nonrelated question to this one. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bw6JsLnx5Jg) is a great video about textures in batch rendering.

Comment: @Sebphil Thank you) But I already based on this Cherno video did batch rendering first in ```C++``` and then in ```Java```. Only here in ```C++``` it works fine and in Java something is not very good or maybe I did something wrong.  But at least I now know exactly where the problem is.